Why is this effective pointer giving a seg fault?
I am writing a compiler into NASM assembly for fun and am stuck trying to implement indexing into an array on the stack.
My compiler generates the following assembly from the input below. I've added comments to explain what is going on.
My code for my compiler
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
exit x[1]

Assembly output
global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1 ; start pushing values in the array to the stack
    push rax 
    mov rax, 2
    push rax 
    mov rax, 3
    push rax 
    mov rax, 4
    push rax
    mov rax, 0x21 ; special byte to denote the end of the array
    push rax, ; finish.
    mov rax, 1 
    push rax ; push the value from the index to the stack
    pop rbx
    mov rax, 8
    imul rbx ; scale the offset by 8 
    sub rax, rsp ; remove the offset from the stack pointer
    mov rax, [rax + 40] ; get the value in the array from the stack
    push rax ; exit with the  array value
    mov rax, 60 
    pop rdi
    syscall

This doesn't work. The line mov rax, [rax + 40] causes a segfault. However, if I manually replace that line with mov rax, [rsp - 8 + 40] the program exits with 1 as expected. Unfortunately I cant do this as there is no way of knowing the value of the index at compile time.
What assembly should I generate to properly index into the array? I naively tried
mov rax, [rsp - (rax * 8) + 40] but this is an invalid effective address since you can't subtract a register in case you escape the buffer.
Thanks!

You're using -rsp? Hmm, very curious.  What formula are you trying to accomplish?

@ErikEidt Not really sure why I chose rsp. I'm loosely following this guide and its what he used there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcSijrRsrY0&list=PLUDlas_Zy_qC7c5tCgTMYq2idyyT241qs I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean by formula.

@ErikEidt Oh my bad I put them the wrong way round. However, I still get the segfault. I've updated the question.

Ok, but rax holds an index/offset not a pointer, so not dereferenceable.

As pointed out by ErikEdit I wrote the sub the wrong way round. oops. I Also did something a bit hacky to avoid modifying rsp. heres the new output. Im not very good at assembly so I'm sure there's a cleaner way. Thanks for the help!
global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1 ; start pushing values in the array to the stack
    push rax 
    mov rax, 2
    push rax 
    mov rax, 3
    push rax 
    mov rax, 4
    push rax
    mov rax, 0x21 ; special byte to denote the end of the array
    push rax, ; finish.
    mov rax, 1 
    push rax ; push the value from the index to the stack
    pop rbx
    mov rax, 8
    imul rbx ; scale the offset by 8 
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rax, rsp
    sub rax, rcx 
    mov rax, [rax + 40] ; get the value in the array from the stack
    push rax ; exit with the  array value
    mov rax, 60 
    pop rdi
    syscall

